# Looking for a function $f$ that is continuous in a point, yet has an infinite derivative in this point

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm looking for a function $f$ that is continuous in $x$, i.e. for which holds
$$\lim_{y\to 0} f(x+y)-f(x) = 0$$
, but for which its derivative
$$ \lim_{y\to 0} \frac {f(x+y)-f(x)}y = \infty$$
tends to infinity.

The whole idea of being continuous in a point, yet having an infinite gradient in this point seems like a contradiction, but as differentiable$\implies$continuous is only an implication, it should be possible.

As a possible candidate I've e.g. looked for solutions for the functional equation $f(x+y) = f(x) + g(y)$, where $f$ is continuous,
but as $f(x) = f(0+x) = g(x) $, the only solution for $f(x)$ is $c\cdot x$, which doesn't fulfill the requirement.

Comment: For example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ at $x=0$. You may take also $x^a$ with $0<a<1$.

Comment: Probably drawing a picture will give you a better approach.  There is a well-known elementary function with this property.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65770/infinite-gradient-and-continuity Might be relevant

Comment: Take $\,f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}\,$ for example. @RobertZ Your $f(x)$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^-$ which can introduce unnecessary confusion, depending on the exact definitions.

Comment: Defined on R. f(x) = √x for x \ge 0 , f(x) = -√|x| for x \le 0.

Comment: Thanks guys! I kinda missed the forest for the trees it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic example (not the simplest possible, of course):

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^3-3x^2}$$

[image]

Infinite derivatives at $x=0$ and $x=3$, continuous everywhere. I still remember this function from my math exam, like 3 decades ago :)